# Reactjs : function.bind(this) causing button to not work

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a function that is supposed to triggered by clicking a button:

```
createUser() {
    console.log("Hi"); // Debug line
    var name = REACTDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.displayName).nodeValue;
    // Some more code
}
```

And my button is declared as below:

```
render() {
    /* Returns the frontend stuff */
    return (
        // Some other stuff...
        <button className="material-button" onClick={this.createUser.bind(this)}>
         Sign Up
         </button>
    );
```

And when I click the button, it looks like the function is not being executed properly. Not even the debug line is logged to the console (I use Nodejs CommandLine). 
I have read question 47624663, but it did not really help. Without the bind(this), clicking the button will cause a run-time error saying that cannot read refs of type undefined.
Any insight could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace createUser on the arrow function

```
createUser = () => {
    console.log("Hi"); // Debug line
    var name = REACTDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.displayName).nodeValue;
    // Some more code
}
```

Comment: Still did not work, nothing appeared on the console :(

Comment: you can see it here https://codepen.io/KoldunMax/pen/omMyWK
it's working, what is the error do you get ?

Comment: Thanks! The message did show up on the link that you shared. It's not showing up on my nodejs commandLine console though. Is it something about Nodejs commandline?

Comment: if you want it shows in node js command line you have to send http request to back end and make console log of the result in Node js code, in your case it'll show up only in the browser console